# uploading user image to strapi using axios

Tags: post, axios, multipartform-data, strapi, http-status-code-500

I'm uploading an image to the users model in strapi using axios post request

**Code**

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();

      bodyFormData.append('files', this.state.avatars, this.state.avatars.name)
      bodyFormData.append('ref', 'users')
      bodyFormData.append('refId', '1')
      bodyFormData.append('field', 'avatar')
      bodyFormData.append('source', 'users-permissions')

      console.log(bodyFormData)
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${strapi}/upload`,
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          }
      }).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>{console.log(err.response.data.message)})
```

**Uploading Image to Strapi**

I'm targeting the avatar field

[image]

however, I'm getting an internal server error

[image]

how to fix this? need help

Comment: [answer is explained here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74509837/15496626)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${strapi}/upload`,
        data: JSON.stringify(bodyFormData),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          }
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the key "ref" to be "User" only not "Users"